# bing maps in windows phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

am developing an app which uses map, and am using html, javascript for developing, i found that there is an extension for windows store app for using bing map, but its not supported in windows phone 8.1 javascript app development. so i hacked into the entension for RT and added to my project, and only error i get is Windows.ApplicationModel.Resource.core.ResourceManager has been deprecated. and i know that other scripts are loading before the map does. and still i couldnt find he solution. here is my code.

default.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>homePage</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/ui.js"></script>

<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/pages/home/home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/pages/home/home.js"></script>

<!-- bing map api-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bing/veapicore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bing/veapiModules.js"></script>
<link href="/css/mapcontrol.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0">
</script>-->

<!-- bing map controls-->
<script src="/js/MapControls.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<!-- The content that will be loaded and displayed. -->
<div class="fragment homepage">
    <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
            <span class="pagetitle">Native</span>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section aria-label="Main content" role="main" style="overflow:auto;">
        <div style="float:left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
            <input type="button" value="Get My Location" onclick="GetMyLocation();" />
            <input type="text" id="txtStart" placeholder="Source" maxlength="50" />
            <input type="text" id="txtEnd" placeholder="Destination" maxlength="50" />
            <input type="button" value="Create Route" onclick="GetRoute();" />
        </div>
       <div id="mapcontainer" style="height:150px;width:150px;"></div>
       <div id='itineraryDiv' style="position:relative; width:40%; height:90%; float: right; overflow:auto; font-family:Verdana, Arial"></div> 
    </section>
</div>
```

mapcontrol.js

```
    (function () {
     function initialize() {
      Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Map', { callback: GetMap });
     }
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize, false);
     })();


      var map, searchManager, directionsManager, loc = null;

      function GetMap() {
       var mapOptions =
       {
        credentials: "bing map key",
        mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road
       };
       map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"),       mapOptions);
        }

        function GetMyLocation() {
           var geolocator = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
           geolocator.getGeopositionAsync().then(function (loc) {
           var mapCenter = map.getCenter();
           mapCenter.latitude = loc.coordinate.latitude;
           mapCenter.longitude = loc.coordinate.longitude;
           map.setView({ center: mapCenter, zoom: 12 });

            var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(loc.coordinate.latitude, loc.coordinate.longitude);
            var pushPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc);
            map.entities.push(pushPin);
           });  
          }

       function geocodeCallback(response, userData) {
          if (response &&
               response.results &&
             response.results.length > 0) {
             var r = response.results[0];
             var l = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(r.location.latitude,                  r.location.longitude);

    //Display result on map       
    var p = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(l);
    map.entities.push(p);

    //Zoom to result
    map.setView({ center: l, zoom: 15 });
     } else {
    ShowMessage("Geocode Response", "Not results found.");
     }
    }

    function GetRoute() {
     ClearMap();

    if (directionsManager) {
       directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode:    Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving });

    var startWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint(
        { address: document.getElementById('txtStart').value });

    var endWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint(
        { address: document.getElementById('txtEnd').value });

    directionsManager.addWaypoint(startWaypoint);
    directionsManager.addWaypoint(endWaypoint);

    directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer:   document.getElementById('itineraryDiv') });
    directionsManager.calculateDirections();
} else {
    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', {
        callback: function () {
            directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

            GetRoute();
            }
        });
     }
 }

   function ClearMap() {
      map.entities.clear();

      if (directionsManager) {
       directionsManager.resetDirections();
     }
    }

   function geocodeError(request) {
    ShowMessage("Geocode Error", "Unable to Geocode request.");
}

  function ShowMessage(title, msg) {
     var m = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(title, msg);
    m.showAsync();
 }
```

the error which i get is.

The method Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceManager.get_DefaultContext has been deprecated. DefaultContext may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows Phone 'OSVersion' (TBD). Instead, use ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView.

it will be so helpful if someone figure it out. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the online URL to Bing Maps V7 or v8 and not the JS files from the Windows 8 API. Note that the Windows 8 API is deprecated in Windows 10.

Comment: Tried it but still it says "cannot load any external file to app"@rbrundritt

Comment: Take a look at these resources: https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/06/28/cross-platform-development-with-bing-maps-and-phonegap/  and    https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cross-Platform-Bing-Maps-e96600d5